# jQuery: Fixed Length, Connected, Sortable Lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a single list that is broken into three columns as follows:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1       4       7
2       5       8
3       6       9
```

The list is continuous from 1 to 9 and each column has a fixed number of rows (3).  I want to allow the user to reorder the list while maintaining my fixed length columns (3 rows).

Making the list sortable via jQuery was fairly easy.

HTML

```
< ul class="sortable" id="column1">
    < li class="section">1< /li>
    < li class="section">2< /li>
    < li class="section">3< /li>
< /ul>
< ul class="sortable" id="column2">
    < li class="section">4< /li>
    < li class="section">5< /li>
    < li class="section">6< /li>
< /ul>
< ul class="sortable" id="column3">
    < li class="section">7< /li>
    < li class="section">8< /li>
    < li class="section">9< /li>
< /ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('#column1').sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    items : ".section"
    });
$('#column2').sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    items : ".section"
    });
$('#column3').sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    items : ".section"
    });
```

This allows me to drag and drop across lists, but I'm not sure how to maintain column length.  Using this method, each list grows and shrinks as items are moved.  Any suggestions on a good method to accomplish this?

**EDITED WITH FULL SOLUTION**

Thanks to both of the responses I got the full solution.  In my question I neglected to mention I had a header in each column.

HTML

```
< ul class="sortable" id="column1">
    < li class="header">Header< /li>
    < li class="section">1< /li>
    < li class="section">2< /li>
    < li class="section">3< /li>
< /ul>
< ul class="sortable" id="column2">
    < li class="header">Header< /li>
    < li class="section">4< /li>
    < li class="section">5< /li>
    < li class="section">6< /li>
< /ul>
< ul class="sortable" id="column3">
    < li class="header">Header< /li>
    < li class="section">7< /li>
    < li class="section">8< /li>
    < li class="section">9< /li>
< /ul>
```

Javascript

```
var colLength = 4;
$('#column1, #column2, #column3').sortable({
    connectWith: ".draftboard",
    items : ".section",
    update : balanceColumns
});
balanceColumns: function(event, ui){
    function balanceColumn1(){
        var col1 = $('#column1 li');
        var col2 = $('#column2 li');
        var col3 = $('#column3 li');
        if (col1.length > colLength){
            col1.last().insertAfter( col2[0] );
        }
        else if(col1.length < colLength){
            col2.parent().children(':nth-child(2)').appendTo(col1.parent());
        }
    }
    function balanceColumn2(){
        var col1 = $('#column1 li');
        var col2 = $('#column2 li');
        var col3 = $('#column3 li');
        if (col2.length > colLength){

            if (col1.length < colLength) {
                col2.parent().children(':nth-child(2)').appendTo(col1.parent());
            } else {
                col2.last().insertAfter( col3[0] );
            }
        }
        else if(col2.length < colLength){
            col3.parent().children(':nth-child(2)').appendTo(col2.parent());
        }
    }
    function balanceColumn3(){
        var col1 = $('#column1 li');
        var col2 = $('#column2 li');
        var col3 = $('#column3 li');
        if (col3.length > colLength) {
            col3.parent().children(':nth-child(2)').appendTo(col2.parent());
            balanceColumn2();
        }
    }
    balanceColumn1();
    balanceColumn2();
    balanceColumn3();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something this way: http://jsfiddle.net/ETGyq/

I'm out of time by now, but I can continue this tomorrow.

Comment: Nice to see you got it. Great.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI's sortable has a [receive](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive) callback that can do something after dropping. So do something like this for each one:

```
$('#column1').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable',
  items: '.section',
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    // check to see which other column has only 2 items in it now (may even be a sortable
    // method that shows origin of drag) and move the 4th item in the current column to it.
    // or otherwise shift the items around according to your logic of where extra items
    // should be shuffled to.
  }
});
```

See the sortable documentation linked above for details about using the `event` and `ui` arguments to target your elements.

NOTE: Since this function will likely be the same for all 3 columns, best practices would suggest you define this receive function once and reference it in each of the 3 sortable inits.

Comment: +1 Spot on.  Wish I could accept your answer too (rcdmk got the plus since he went through the trouble to write out the whole routine).